# Detect which form input has focus using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, forms

How do you detect which form input has focus using JavaScript or jQuery?

From within a function I want to be able to determine which form input has focus.  I'd like to be able to do this in straight JavaScript and/or jQuery.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way, but you could try:

```
var selectedInput = null;
$(function() {
    $('input, textarea, select').focus(function() {
        selectedInput = this;
    }).blur(function(){
        selectedInput = null;
    });
});
```

Comment: Very unneficient for large DOM structures, does not support adding elements dynamically, what about links?. Surprised this was chosen as the right answer

Comment: @Juan Mendes: Not everything has to be an across the board solution for every situation. Believe it or not, most of the time you'll have < 10 inputs and no dynamically added fields and this will work just fine.

Comment: Most of the time, less than 10 inputs and not adding them dynamically? Maybe for simple forms, not for complex web apps. if document.activeElement is available in all grade A browsers, why would you use a more complex and technically inferior solution? Also, If focus goes to a link, this will give you a false positive. I'm just warning the OP.

Comment: Agreed. Could be very inefficient way of doing things, but hard to find a better solution if you only want to know the last textbox/textarea/dropdown with focus and you don't care about things like buttons etc.

Comment: @Chaos. What do you mean it's hard to find a better solution? Just check the value of `document.activeElement`. See my answer

Answer (score 62):

[`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement), it's been supported in IE for a long time and the latest versions of FF and chrome support it also. If nothing has focus, it returns the `document.body` object.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is change the CSS for a particular form field when it gets focus, you could use the CSS ":focus" selector.  For compatibility with IE6 which doesn't support this, you could use the [IE7](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) library.

Comment: `$('#some_id_here input[type=text]:focus')` will work for text inputs.

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me - is there a new ":focus" selector?

Comment: I'm talking about a CSS selector, not a jQuery selector.

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise, you could use the onfocus and onblur events.

something like:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="txtfocus=1" onblur="txtfocus=0" />
```

and then have something like this in your javascript

```
if (txtfocus==1)
{
//Whatever code you want to run
}

if (txtfocus==0)
{
//Something else here
}
```

But that would just be my way of doing it, and it might not be extremely practical if you have, say 10 inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:  I used a function that would return a 1 if the ID of the element it was sent was one that would trigger my event, and all others would return a 0, and the "if" statement would then just fall-through and not do anything:

```
function getSender(field) {
    switch (field.id) {
        case "someID":
        case "someOtherID":
            return 1;
        break;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

function doSomething(elem) {
    if (getSender(elem) == 1) {
       // do your stuff
    }
  /*  else {
       // do something else
    }  */
}
```

HTML Markup:

```
<input id="someID" onfocus="doSomething(this)" />
<input id="someOtherID" onfocus="doSomething(this)" />
<input id="someOtherGodForsakenID" onfocus="doSomething(this)" />
```

The first two will do the event in doSomething, the last one won't (or will do the else clause if uncommented).

-Tom

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for text/password/textarea (not sure if I forgot others that can get focus, but they could be easily added by modifying the if clauses... an improvement could be made on the design by putting the if's body in it's own function to determine suitable inputs that can get focus).

Assuming that you can rely on the user sporting a browser that is not pre-historic (http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=dataset):

```
        <script>
        //The selector to get the text/password/textarea input that has focus is: jQuery('[data-selected=true]')
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('body').bind({'focusin': function(Event){
                var Target = jQuery(Event.target);
                if(Target.is(':text')||Target.is(':password')||Target.is('textarea'))
                {
                    Target.attr('data-selected', 'true');
                }
            }, 'focusout': function(Event){
                var Target = jQuery(Event.target);
                if(Target.is(':text')||Target.is(':password')||Target.is('textarea'))
                {
                    Target.attr('data-selected', 'false');
                }
            }});
        });
    </script>
```

For pre-historic browsers, you can use the uglier:

```
        <script>
        //The selector to get the text/password/textarea input that has focus is: jQuery('[name='+jQuery('body').data('Selected_input')+']')
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('body').bind({'focusin': function(Event){
                var Target = jQuery(Event.target);
                if(Target.is(':text')||Target.is(':password')||target.is('textarea'))
                {
                    jQuery('body').data('Selected_input', Target.attr('name'));
                }
            }, 'focusout': function(Event){
                var Target = jQuery(Event.target);
                if(Target.is(':text')||Target.is(':password')||target.is('textarea'))
                {
                    jQuery('body').data('Selected_input', null);
                }
            }});
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one listener if you use event bubbling (and bind it to the document); one per form is reasonable, though:

```
var selectedInput = null;
$(function() {
    $('form').on('focus', 'input, textarea, select', function() {
        selectedInput = this;
     }).on('blur', 'input, textarea, select', function() {
        selectedInput = null;
    });
});
```

(Maybe you should move the selectedInput variable to the form.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<input type="text" onfocus="myFunction()">
```

It triggers the function when the input is focused.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer
```