# JavaScript / jQuery: Test if window has focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

How do you test if the browser has focus?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483741/how-to-determine-which-html-page-element-has-focus which can answer this question as well.

Comment: Try `document.hasFocus()`, which returns a boolean. 

It's built into the spec, so it can be done without jQuery.

Comment: For someone who want check pages' visibility (which is _not_ as same as focus), please checkout [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) for more details.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I haven't tested this in other browsers, but it seems to work in Webkit. I'll let you try IE. :o)

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/ScKbk/

After you click to start the interval, change the focus of the browser window to see the result change. Again, tested only in Webkit.

```
var window_focus;

$(window).focus(function() {
    window_focus = true;
}).blur(function() {
    window_focus = false;
});

$(document).one('click', function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('body').append('has focus? ' + window_focus + '<br>');
    }, 1000);
});​
```

Comment: @jball - Must be IE? In Webkit and Firefox any activation of the window triggers the focus. I wonder if there's a workaround for IE. Also, did you test on your page? Maybe there an issue because the jsFiddle uses frames?

Comment: Chrome actually. After further testing, my first comment might be wrong - the tab key breaking it seems to be more consistent.

Comment: @jball - I'm guessing that the tab key breaks it because jsFiddle has lots of input elements in other frames. Get rid of the frames, and I'll bet it will work a little better for you.

Comment: I believe each frame has its own `window` object, so if you were to use frames, you would probably just need to include the script in each one.

Comment: Use `window.top` to check the topmost window.

Comment: This works when returning to the page from doing something in a popup, cheers!

Comment: Is there a way to check the result on page/tab/window load without using click function ?

Answer (score 163):

use the hasFocus method of the document.
You can find detailed description and an example here:
[hasFocus method](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmnivgu.php)

**EDIT:** Added fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Msjyv/3/

*HTML*

```
Currently <b id="status">without</b> focus...
```

*JS*

```
function check()
{
    if(document.hasFocus() == lastFocusStatus) return;

    lastFocusStatus = !lastFocusStatus;
    statusEl.innerText = lastFocusStatus ? 'with' : 'without';
}

window.statusEl = document.getElementById('status');
window.lastFocusStatus = document.hasFocus();

check();
setInterval(check, 200);
```

Comment: I tried the example from the above link and it worked well in IE7+, Chrome, and FF4. +1 for you.

Comment: Great little function, works much better than other jQuery equivalents I have run across.

Comment: More useful than the accepted answer, I had problems with the timer loading while the window was out of focus.

Comment: This is not supported by Opera. The calming fact is that they are in process of switching the rendering engine to Webkit :)

Comment: In the meantime you can use some thing like this to get the functionality in Opera:

`if(typeof document.hasFocus === 'undefined') {
 document.hasFocus = function () {
  return document.visibilityState == 'visible';
 } 
}`

Comment: currently `document.hasFocus` always returns true on Mac Chromium, so you should use another approach until the bug is fixed

Comment: this solution works on IE9, FF 28.0 and Chrome 34.x. Previously I tried with window.onfocus and window.onblur. that worked in FF and Chrome but not in IE.

Comment: The solution will now work in all browsers, including the latest Opera since they recently converted their rendering engine to Webkit.

Comment: @sNiCKY It is `document.hasFocus()` to check the visibility state. `document.hasFocus` returns `true` for the property's existence only.

Comment: Does this work on mobile browsers? On some devices, some mobile browser window threads and timers are frozen when not active, no?

Comment: This answer/question is a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354718/detect-which-form-input-has-focus-using-javascript-or-jquery The accepted answer is a hack whereas the most upvoted answer contains a much simpler answer from the standards.

Answer (score 3):

### Simple javascript snippet

#### Event based:

```js
function focuschange(fclass) {
    var elems=['textOut','textFocus'];
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
        document.getElementById(elems[i]).
            setAttribute('class',fclass);
    }
}
window.addEventListener("blur",function(){focuschange('havnt')});
window.addEventListener("focus",function(){focuschange('have')});
focuschange('havnt');
```

```css
.have                { background:#CFC; }
#textOut.have:after  { content:'';      }
.havnt               { background:#FCC; }
#textOut.havnt:after { content:' not';  }
```

```html
<span id='textOut'>Have</span><span id='textFocus'> focus</span>
```

#### Interval pool based:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    var fclass='havnt';
    if (document.hasFocus()) {
      fclass='have';
    };
    var elems=['textOut','textFocus'];
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++) {
        document.getElementById(elems[i]).
            setAttribute('class',fclass);
    }
},100);
```

```css
#textOut.have:after  { content:'';     }
#textOut.havnt:after { content:' not'; }
.have  { background:#CFC; }
.havnt { background:#FCC; }
```

```html
<span id='textOut'>Have</span><span id='textFocus'> focus</span>
```

Comment: I like this answer because of the *event based solution*. Imho, it should be the prefered way always.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<button id="clear">clear log</button>
<div id="event"></div>​
```

Javascript:

```
$(function(){

    $hasFocus = false;

    $('#clear').bind('click', function() { $('#event').empty(); });

    $(window)
        .bind('focus', function(ev){
            $hasFocus = true;
            $('#event').append('<div>'+(new Date()).getTime()+' focus</div>');
        })
        .bind('blur', function(ev){
            $hasFocus = false;
            $('#event').append('<div>'+(new Date()).getTime()+' blur</div>');
        })
        .trigger('focus');

    setInterval(function() {
        $('#event').append('<div>'+(new Date()).getTime()+' has focus '+($hasFocus ? 'yes' : 'no')+'</div>');
    }, 1000);
});​
```

[test](http://jsfiddle.net/QkzvP/)

UPDATE:

I'll fix it, but IE does not work very well

[test update](http://jsfiddle.net/QkzvP/1/)

Comment: Apparently blur doesn't fire when when switching tabs. :(