# Detect tab/window activation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, dom

It seems that Google+ checks for notification updates when I activate the tab in Firefox

It'd show "0" every time I activate it, but change to a number of new notifications in a couple of seconds after that.

What's the mechanism allowing to tap into that event? Is there a specific DOM event for that? Or are they using something like *onmouseover* handler and just consider any kind of activity to be a sufficient indicator of tab activation?

Comment: See this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479734/test-if-window-has-focus

Answer (score 11):

There is [Page visibility](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/#onvisiblitychange-event-handler) document, which describes [document.onvisibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onvisibilitychange#Example) event handler.

The usage

```
document.onvisibilitychange = function() { 
  console.log("Visibility of page has changed!");
};
```

Answer (score 9):

Just a guess because I haven't all relevant browsers available for testing.

What about using the `focus` event on the `window`. Whenever a user clicks somewhere this is invoked but also on switching of tabs. To distinguish between a user's actions on the page and a user switching to the page you could check if the event's `explicitOriginalTarget` points to the `window`.

```
window.onfocus=function(event){
    if(event.explicitOriginalTarget===window){
        console.log('switched from tab');
    }
}
```

Comment: `explicitOriginalTarget`is a Mozilla Firefox only property. Doesn't work on major Browsers like Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately there's no 100% accurate solution

`onvisibilitychange` correctly triggers on tab changes, but does not trigger on window changes (ALT+TAB) [visibilitychange event is not triggered when switching program/window with ALT+TAB or clicking in taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993157/visibilitychange-event-is-not-triggered-when-switching-program-window-with-altt)

---

`window.onfocus` triggers when the document becomes focused. This works as expected if the tab's focus is already inside the web page, then it correctly triggers when *window* or *tab* becomes focused.

But if you have the focus on the URL bar, or in the console, you are already "out of focus", and when you get out of the *window* or *tab* and return, you will remain "out of focus", so this event won't trigger until you click inside the page, or navigate into it through TAB key

---

You can test below how each event triggers (click inside the white iframe to test onfocus/onblur events)

```js
window.onfocus = () => console.log("focus");

window.onblur = () => console.log("out of focus");

document.onvisibilitychange = () => console.log("visibilityState: ", document.visibilityState);
```