# visibilitychange event is not triggered when switching program/window with ALT+TAB or clicking in taskbar

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, dom-events

The problem is with the behaviour of the event "visibilitychange".

**It's triggered:**
 - When I switch to a different tab inside the browser window.

- When I click in minimize / restore buttons for the browser window.

*(this is ok)*

**It's not triggered:**
 - When I switch to a different window/program using ALT+TAB.

- When I switch to a different window/program clicking on taskbar.

*(this SHOULD trigger, because, just like when minimizing, the window's visibility may change)*

---

**W3 Page Visibility API Documentation**: http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/

*There is no definition of "page visibility" regarding <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>/program switching in the spec sheet. I'm guessing it has something to do in between the OS and the Browser.*

---

### TESTED IN

- **Browsers**:
  Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m / Firefox 36.0.1 / Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17107
- **OS**: Windows 8.1

---

Is there a workaround to fix this behaviour? The implementation is fairly simple, I listen to the "visibilitychange" event using jQuery, and then in its callback, I check for the value of "document.visibilityState", but the problem is that the event is not firing when expected.

```
$(document).on('visibilitychange', function() {

    if(document.visibilityState == 'hidden') {
        // page is hidden
    } else {
        // page is visible
    }
});
```

This can be done without jQuery too, but the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and taskbar switch hide/show expected behaviour is still missing:

```
if(document.addEventListener){
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        // check for page visibility
    });
}
```

I've also tried the ifvisible.js module (https://github.com/serkanyersen/ifvisible.js) but the behaviour is the same.

```
ifvisible.on('blur', function() {
    // page is hidden
});

ifvisible.on('focus', function() {
    // page is visible
});
```

I haven't tested in other browsers because if I can't make it work in Chrome on Windows I really don't care about the other browsers yet.

Any help or suggestions?

---

### UPDATE

I tried using different vendor prefixes for the event name (visibilitychange, webkitvisibilitychange, mozvisibilitychange, msvisibilitychange) but but still the event is not triggered when I switch to a different program in the taskbar or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, or even if I open the start menu thing in windows with the windows key, which covers the whole screen.

I can reproduce the exact same issue in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

### UPDATE #2

[Here's](https://stereologics.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/about-page-visibility-api-hidden-visibilitychange-visibilitystate/) a roundup post I wrote for this issue and a workaround in pure Javascript to solve the encountered problems.

### UPDATE #3

Edited to include a copy of the sourced blog post. (see accepted answer)

Comment: Hi bb,
The link you are provided not working. Can you please tell me the workaround you find.

Comment: hey, i edited the link, the post is now at: https://stereologics.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/about-page-visibility-api-hidden-visibilitychange-visibilitystate/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Here's](https://stereologics.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/about-page-visibility-api-hidden-visibilitychange-visibilitystate/) a roundup post I wrote for this issue and a workaround in pure JavaScript to solve the encountered problems.

**Edited to include a copy of the sourced blog post:**

---

> In any kind of javascript application we develop there may be a
> feature or any change in the application which reacts according to the
> current user visibility state, this could be to pause a playing video
> when the user ALT+TABs to a different window, tracking stats about how
> the users interact with our application, how often does him switch to
> a different tab, how long does it take him to return and a lot of
> performance improvements that can benefit from this kind of API.
>
> The Page Visibility API provides us with two top-level attributes:
> document.hidden (boolean) and document.visibilityState (which could be
> any of these strings: “hidden”, “visible”, “prerender”, “unloaded”).
> This would not be not good enough without an event we could listen to
> though, that’s why the API also provides the useful visibilitychange
> event.
>
> So, here’s a basic example on how we could take action on a visibility
> change:
>
> ```
> function handleVisibilityChange() {
>   if(document.hidden) {
>     // the page is hidden
>   } else {
>     // the page is visible
>   }
> }
>
> document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
> ```
>
> We could also check for document.visibilityState value.
>
> Dealing with vendor issues George Berkeley by John Smibert
>
> Some of the implementations on some browsers still need that the
> attributes or even the event name is vendor-prefixed, this means we
> may need to listen to the msvisibilitychange event or check for the
> document.webkitHidden or the document.mozHidden attributes. In order
> to do so, we should check if any vendor-prefixed attribute is set, and
> once we know which one is the one used in the current browser (only if
> there’s the need for a prefix), we can name the event and attributes
> properly.
>
> Here’s an example approach on how to handle these prefixes:
>
> ```
> var browserPrefixes = ['moz', 'ms', 'o', 'webkit'];
>
> // get the correct attribute name
> function getHiddenPropertyName(prefix) {
>   return (prefix ? prefix + 'Hidden' : 'hidden');
> }
>
> // get the correct event name
> function getVisibilityEvent(prefix) {
>   return (prefix ? prefix : '') + 'visibilitychange';
> }
>
> // get current browser vendor prefix
> function getBrowserPrefix() {
>   for (var i = 0; i < browserPrefixes.length; i++) {
>     if(getHiddenPropertyName(browserPrefixes[i]) in document) {
>       // return vendor prefix
>       return browserPrefixes[i];
>     }
>   }
>
>   // no vendor prefix needed
>   return null;
> }
>
> // bind and handle events
> var browserPrefix = getBrowserPrefix();
>
> function handleVisibilityChange() {
>   if(document[getHiddenPropertyName(browserPrefix )]) {
>     // the page is hidden
>     console.log('hidden');
>   } else {
>     // the page is visible
>     console.log('visible');
>   }
> }
>
> document.addEventListener(getVisibilityEvent(browserPrefix), handleVisibilityChange, false);
> ```
>
> Other issues There is a challenging issue around the “Page Visibility”
> definition: how to determine if the application is visible or not if
> the window focus is lost for another window, but not the actual
> visibility on the screen? what about different kinds of visibility
> lost, like ALT+TAB, WIN/MAC key (start menu / dash), taskbar/dock
> actions, WIN+L (lock screen), window minimize, window close, tab
> switching. What about the behaviour on mobile devices?
>
> There’s lots of ways in which we may lose or gain visibility and a lot
> of possible interactions between the browser and the OS, therefore I
> don’t think there’s a proper and complete “visible page” definition in
> the W3C spec. This is the definition we get for the document.hidden
> attribute:
>
> HIDDEN ATTRIBUTE On getting, the hidden attribute MUST return true if
> the Document contained by the top level browsing context (root window
> in the browser’s viewport) [HTML5] is not visible at all. The
> attribute MUST return false if the Document contained by the top level
> browsing context is at least partially visible on at least one screen.
>
> If the defaultView of the Document is null, on getting, the hidden
> attribute MUST return true.
>
> To accommodate accessibility tools that are typically full screen but
> still show a view of the page, when applicable, this attribute MAY
> return false when the User Agent is not minimized but is fully
> obscured by other applications.
>
> I’ve found several inconsistencies on when the event is actually
> fired, for example (Chrome 41.0.2272.101 m, on Windows 8.1) the event
> is not fired when I ALT+TAB to a different window/program nor when I
> ALT+TAB again to return, but it IS fired if I CTRL+TAB and then
> CTRL+SHIFT+TAB to switch between browser tabs. It’s also fired when I
> click on the minimize button, but it’s not fired if the window is not
> maximized and I click my editor window which is behing the browser
> window. So the behaviour of this API and it’s different
> implementations are still obscure.
>
> A workaround for this, is to compensate taking advantage of the better
> implemented focus and blur events, and making a custom approach to the
> whole “Page Visibility” issue using an internal flag to prevent
> multiple executions, this is what I’ve come up with:
>
> ```
> var browserPrefixes = ['moz', 'ms', 'o', 'webkit'],
>     isVisible = true; // internal flag, defaults to true
>
> // get the correct attribute name
> function getHiddenPropertyName(prefix) {
>   return (prefix ? prefix + 'Hidden' : 'hidden');
> }
>
> // get the correct event name
> function getVisibilityEvent(prefix) {
>   return (prefix ? prefix : '') + 'visibilitychange';
> }
>
> // get current browser vendor prefix
> function getBrowserPrefix() {
>   for (var i = 0; i < browserPrefixes.length; i++) {
>     if(getHiddenPropertyName(browserPrefixes[i]) in document) {
>       // return vendor prefix
>       return browserPrefixes[i];
>     }
>   }
>
>   // no vendor prefix needed
>   return null;
> }
>
> // bind and handle events
> var browserPrefix = getBrowserPrefix(),
>     hiddenPropertyName = getHiddenPropertyName(browserPrefix),
>     visibilityEventName = getVisibilityEvent(browserPrefix);
>
> function onVisible() {
>   // prevent double execution
>   if(isVisible) {
>     return;
>   }
>  
>   // change flag value
>   isVisible = true;
>   console.log('visible');
> }
>
> function onHidden() {
>   // prevent double execution
>   if(!isVisible) {
>     return;
>   }
>
>   // change flag value
>   isVisible = false;
>   console.log('hidden');
> }
>
> function handleVisibilityChange(forcedFlag) {
>   // forcedFlag is a boolean when this event handler is triggered by a
>   // focus or blur eventotherwise it's an Event object
>   if(typeof forcedFlag === "boolean") {
>     if(forcedFlag) {
>       return onVisible();
>     }
>
>     return onHidden();
>   }
>
>   if(document[hiddenPropertyName]) {
>     return onHidden();
>   }
>
>   return onVisible();
> }
>
> document.addEventListener(visibilityEventName, handleVisibilityChange, false);
>
> // extra event listeners for better behaviour
> document.addEventListener('focus', function() {
>   handleVisibilityChange(true);
> }, false);
>
> document.addEventListener('blur', function() {
>   handleVisibilityChange(false);
> }, false);
>
> window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
>     handleVisibilityChange(true);
> }, false);
>
> window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
>   handleVisibilityChange(false);
> }, false);
> ```
>
> I welcome any feedback on this workaround. Some other great sources
> for ideas on this subject:
>
> Using the Page Visibility API Using PC Hardware more efficiently in
> HTML5: New Web Performance APIs, Part 2 Introduction to the Page
> Visibility API Conclusion The technologies of the web are continuously
> evolving, we’re still recovering from a dark past where tables where
> the markup king, where semantics didn’t mattered, and they weren’t any
> standards around how a browser should render a page.
>
> It’s important we push these new standards forward, but sometimes our
> development requirements make us still need to adapt to these kind of
> transitions, by handling vendor prefixes, testing in different
> browsers and differents OSs or depend on third-party tools to properly
> identify this differences.
>
> We can only hope for a future where the W3C specifications are
> strictly revised, strictly implemented by the browser developer teams,
> and maybe one day we will have a common standard for all of us to work
> with.
>
> As for the Page Visibility API let’s just kinda cite George Berkeley
> and say that:
>
> “being visible” is being perceived.

Comment: This is one of those situations where it's beneficial to actually give the answer in the answer (linked website is dead).

Comment: sorry, i fixed the link, the post is https://stereologics.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/about-page-visibility-api-hidden-visibilitychange-visibilitystate/

Comment: @agbb as he said, you need to give the actual answer instead of linking. Links die (as happened once, and will happen again)

Comment: In case the link does die: https://web.archive.org/web/20180912061844/https://stereologics.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/about-page-visibility-api-hidden-visibilitychange-visibilitystate/

Comment: Thanks, edited to include a copy of the sourced blog post too.

Comment: `blur` event is also firing on alert(), prompt() and confirm().. any way to restrict that?

Answer (score 6):

we can do like below when switching between tabs and switching between applications

```
 var pageVisible = true;  
 function handleVisibilityChange() {
      if (document.hidden) {
        pageVisible = false;
      } else  {
        pageVisible = true;
      }
      console.log("handleVisibilityChange")
      console.log("pageVisible", pageVisible)
      // some function call
    }
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
    window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        pageVisible = true;
        // some function call 
    }, false);
    window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
      pageVisible = false;
      // some function call  
    }, false);
```

Comment: It's important to call window.focus() on page load, otherwise it won't be listening for blur event unless user interacts with document.

Answer (score 4):

A working solution is proposed described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9502074/698168. It uses a combination of the W3C Page Visibility API, blur/focus and mouse movements. Hidden HTML pages related to Alt+Tab are identified in a probabilistic way (i.e. you cannot determine if your page is hidden with 100% accuracy).

Comment: Upvoted because you linked to an answer I previously upvoted while doing related work. That and because the selected answer here has a meager 7 votes and looks like a bunny hole for sure.

Answer (score -3):

There's a very simple solution to this I have come across.

You just need to pass false to the useCapture while attaching an event listener to the document. Works like a charm!

```
 document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {
  // code goes here
}, false)
```

Comment: I think this could be related to the last edition of the Page Visibility specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/), on relatively new browsers this may work better than described in the original question. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange for a browser compatibility chart.

Comment: I had it with false and it still doesn't work in either latest Chrome (56.0) or latest Firefox (52.0)

Comment: False is the default, so this won't change anything.

Comment: Tested in Vivaldi 2.3.1440.60 without success.

Comment: The inadequacies is discussed in the accepted solution above, in short this DOES NOT take into account when you switch program/app, only switch between tabs.

Comment: Um... when a property, or an event, or an attribute is associated with the `document` prototype... why would you assume it WOULD fire at a system OS level event? You're trying to add JS to a page rendered in what amounts to a sandboxed process of a browser. It SHOULDN'T be able to detect that state. Frankly, I'm not huge on the idea the window could either. There's precious few reasons to sandbox bust like that. Say I'm a process that gets injected on page load that only runs when the browser is minimized to mask detection?