# Javascript - Detect when user switches to another application

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am working on a web application that plays videos. I need to detect when the user switches to another application so that I can pause the video.

E.g. the browser is still open in the background but the user is now busy in Skype or some other app.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: @ritaj, thanks. But that event is only triggered when the user navigates away from the page using a link or the browser back button.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', (event) => {
    if (document.visibilityState != 'visible'){
        window.location.href = "Alert.html"
        }
    })
```

Comment: This might not always be reliable if the user has disabled the Visibility API in their web browser, e.g. with [Disable Page Visibility API](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/disable-page-visibility) extension for Firefox.

Comment: This won't work when switching apps (will work for minimizing and switching tabs within the browser): 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993157/visibilitychange-event-is-not-triggered-when-switching-program-window-with-altt