# Automatically close a browser window when the user clicks outside it

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to automatically close a web browser window (e. g., in Google Chrome) when the user clicks outside the window? In order to do this, there would need to be some method for detecting whether or not the window was focused, and also a method for closing the window.

Comment: I suppose I could use window.close() to close the window, but I'd still need some way to detect whether or not the window was focused.

Comment: Details about detecting window focus can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479734/test-if-window-has-focus

Comment: You can edit your question to add what you wrote as comments.

Comment: Just out of interest what is the use case for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most current browsers only let you close the child windows of a parent.
You can't close the master parent window through a script.

Comment: In that case, how can I use Javascript to close a child window?

Answer (score 0):

By default most browsers do not allow javascript to close windows that were not opened by javascript itself. But if you use e.g. `window.open(...)` you can close that window with `window.close()`.

So **if** you have a window opened by javascript you can do the following:

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function(){window.close();}, false);
```