# jquery mobile + interval : can't stop running in the background

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, setinterval, clearinterval

I am using jQuery mobile and I just want to have a counter indicating the time spent on the page. The problem is that I can't stop the counter beeing incremented in the background when the user is **not** seeing the page. Here is my code:

**Page 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page 1</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
            $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false; 
        });

        var interval_id;

        function checkEverySecond() {
            $("#counter").html(parseInt($("#counter").html()) + 1);
        };

        $(document).bind("pageshow", function(){
            interval_id = setInterval(function() {checkEverySecond()}, 1000);
        });

        $(document).bind("pagehide", function(){
            clearInterval(interval_id);
        });
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p id="counter">0</p>
        <a href="page2.html">Go to page 2</a>
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

**Page 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Page 2</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <a href="page1.html">Go to page 1</a>   
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change your code, jQm page events are working a little bit different. You were binding page events to the every page, and the was a problem. You need to bind them to a single page.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/DU493/

```
    var timerObject = {
        interval_id : null
    }

    function checkEverySecond() {
        $("#counter").html(parseInt($("#counter").html()) + 1);
    };        

    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page1', function(){   
            timerObject.interval_id = setInterval(function() {checkEverySecond()}, 1000);    
    }); 

    $(document).on('pagehide', '#page1', function(){   
            clearInterval(timerObject.interval_id);  
    });
```

My example is 1 html multipage template but same thing will work the same with multiple html files.

**EDIT :**

Reason it didn't work in your multi html example was because **bind** was used instead **of** on. Also mobileinit should be declared before jQuery Mobile is loaded.

Comment: I understand where I was wrong (not specifying the '#page1') and I agree that it is working on you jsFiddle but it is not working on my multiple html files example! :(

Comment: If you want archive your example and send it to my email: dragan.gaic@gmail.com , I will fix it for you.

Comment: Fix sent, I will add it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could increment when the window has focus:

```
var window_focus;

$(window).focus(function() {
    window_focus = true;
})

while (window_focus) {
    checkEverySecond()
}
```

[JavaScript / jQuery: Test if window has focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479734/javascript-jquery-test-if-window-has-focus)

Comment: Nice try but it's not working. Firstly, I guess it would not be executed every second but constantly. Secondly, it seems not be compatible with "jquery mobile philosophy".