# on jquery's focusout, detect whether the focus shifted or no elements have focus

Tags: jquery, focus

I'm using jquery 1.8.2, have 2 input fields and would like a way to detect whether each one has focus, or neither have focus.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit:

I've updated the jsfiddle to be closer to what I want so there isn't confusion.  The problem here is I have 2 input fields which are tied together.  I want to grow one and shrink the other when the one is focused, and I want to reset both to their original widths if neither is focused.  I could get heavy handed with some global variables that update on focus and keep track of whether both are in or out of focus but I wanted to see if a jquery solution existed first.  Here is the updated jsfiddle with a button to toggle the reset animation so you can see how it hops at the moment:

http://jsfiddle.net/LZn85/12/

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<input class="searchy-search input1" />
<input class="searchy-search input2" />
<p>who has focus?</p>
<div class="focus-who jquery-focus"></div>

<button class="out-focus">toggle focus out</button>​

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.focus-who').html('init');
    $('.input1').val('some long string of text');
    $('.input2').val('some long string of text');

    $('.searchy-search').focusin(function() { 
        var $shrinkSelector;
        if($(this).hasClass('input1')) {
            $shrinkSelector = $('.input2');
        } else if($(this).hasClass('input2')) {
            $shrinkSelector = $('.input1');
        }   
        var initWidth = 100;
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var inputLength = inputVal.length;

        if(inputLength > 16) {
            var offset = ((inputLength - 16) * 6); 
            var growWidth = initWidth + offset;
            var shrinkWidth = initWidth - offset;
            var aniTime = 200;
            $(this).animate({width: growWidth + 'px'}, aniTime);
            $shrinkSelector.animate({width: shrinkWidth + 'px'}, aniTime);
        }  
    });
    var outFocus = false;
    $('.out-focus').click(function() {
        outFocus = !outFocus;
    });
    $('.searchy-search').focusout(function() {
        if(outFocus) {
            $('.searchy-search').animate({width: '130px'}, 200);
        }
    });
});​
```

another edit:

looks like this might just be my best option.  If anyone has any other ideas that would be great, but for now I think I'll just have to go with this.

[Detect which form input has focus using JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354718/detect-which-form-input-has-focus-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work with the focusout event because the focusout event happens before the focus event. So your code is firing before the browser knows what element now has focus. Is there a reason why it has to check on the focusout event? You could do something that uses both the focus and focusout events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.focus-who').html('init');

   $('.searchy-search').focus(function() {
       $('.jquery-focus').html($(this).attr("id"));
   });

   $('.searchy-search').focusout(function() {
       $('.jquery-focus').html("nothin");
   });
});​
```

Comment: the reason is I am growing each input on focus and shrinking the other because they are tied.  I updated my jsfiddle to run these animations, along with a button to toggle the focus out reset behavior so you can see how it hops when I move from one input to the next:  http://jsfiddle.net/LZn85/12/

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear what you're looking to do, but this might help.

You can detect whether focus has moved away from all children of a parent element `parentEl`:

```
  // Trigger when any children have lost focus
  parentEl.on('focusout', function() {
    // Check where focus has moved to
    setTimeout(function() {
      if(parentEl.find(":focus").length == 0){
        // Focus has moved outside the parent element
      }else{
        // Focus has moved to another element within the parent element
      }
    }, 50)
  });
```

The 50ms `setTimeout` gives the browser a chance to move the focus to the new elements before we check.

Comment: Does 50 have significance? Does 0 not work under certain scenarios or browsers?

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work on divs inside of the parent. They don't seem to get the focus bit when clicked on.