# How to detect focus changed event in JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function, this function can detect whether the focus is on the certain element.If the focus is on the element, I call the `onfocus()` function, and if not on the element, I do nothing.How can I do this?

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.activeElement

Comment: OK,let me hava a check

Comment: I use thie like `var curElement = document.activeElement;` but when I check the `curElement`, it returns undefined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many different ways to do this.

**Here is 2 examples:**

**Solution #1:**

You could use simple inline `onblur` function to see if that certain element is focused out. This is probably the simplest way to do it.

```
<input type="text" onblur="javascript:alert('You have focused out');" />
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Tj3/1/)**

**Solution #2:**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
var selectedInput = null;
$(function() {
    $('input').focus(function() {
        selectedInput = this;
    }).blur(function(){
        selectedInput = null;
        alert("You have focused out");
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Tj3/)**

If you want multiple, you could use:

```
$('input, textarea, select').focus(function() {
```

**[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/354849/3739658)**

You could use `blur` and `focus` functions to see if that certain element is focused.

Comment: Yeah, this is good, but when I leave this element and on another element, I can not know I am not on the `text` element. Right?

Comment: When you leave the element, it should detect that you left the element because of the `onblur` inline function :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, the `onblur` attribute is what I said, thank you very much~

Comment: `$("*").focus()`, I guess?

Comment: The whole JavaScript scene on StackOverflow is just ruined. Unless someone defines explicitly that they want JQuery, then JavaScript means just that -- clean JavaScript.

Frameworks come and go, and since people somehow imagine replying with jQuery explicit code is OK -- StackOverflow is swamped with hundreds of thousands of replies like this, where you mistake a framework for a language or platform!

Comment: @JonLennartAasenden there is context. in 2014 jQuery was the defacto way to do JS because JS was lacking many basic features. things have changed, and the site still has some old answers like this one.