# Issue with getting focus

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, src

I'm trying to change the img if the user clicks anywhere inside the specified div element. Nothing is happening, i know something must be wrong.

So far i have this

```js
setInterval("myFunction()", 1);

function myFunction() {
 
    if document.getElementById("demo").hasFocus; {
        document.getElementById('pic1').src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/701853789855346689/iKxIyGkO.png';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('pic1').src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/688766010837446657/2DgfpAQ6.png';
    }
}
```

```html
<div style="border-style: solid;height:20px;" id="demo"></div>

<img id="pic1" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/688766010837446657/2DgfpAQ6.png">
```

Comment: that isn't valid javascript

Comment: give the div a width

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you Daniel for the help.

Comment: Validate your code, then edit your post.

Comment: @skav That wouldn't matter man.

Comment: @L3SAN if you run the snippet, you can clearly tell your code is invalid, due diligence is expected. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You probably meant to nest image in div?

Comment: @JuanMendes I understand, i'm also learning at the same time.

Comment: If your question was "why am I getting a syntax error?", that would be a valid question showing some due dilligence

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm getting right what you're trying to do. You can see a working code here :

You had some typos in your code and missed the parenthesis for the `if` condition

```js
var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
demo.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);

function myFunction() {

  if (document.getElementById("demo") === document.activeElement) {
    document.getElementById('pic1').src = 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/701853789855346689/iKxIyGkO.png';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('pic1').src = 'https://screenshots.fr.sftcdn.net/fr/scrn/76000/76818/microsoft-small-basic-22.jpg';
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="border-style: solid;height:20px;" id="demo"></div>

<img id="pic1" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/688766010837446657/2DgfpAQ6.png">
```

Comment: You didn't mention the most important part, [document.activeElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354718/detect-which-form-input-has-focus-using-javascript-or-jquery/4455401#4455401)

Comment: That's it! You used the onclick i see. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept my answer if your problem is solved. You should also read doc for activeElement as Juan Mendes suggested : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement

Comment: @Lau Question, the first image src set in that js doesn't get used? I know it's the same image as the html img tag originally.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the else part. you are missing `d` for document in `ocument.getElementById('pic1').src`

Comment: That's two of them..

Comment: @L3SAN again you made a mistake in if condition. `;` should not be there. please edit  it. if document.getElementById("demo").hasFocus`;` {

Comment: `if (document.getElementById("demo").hasFocus)` is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions evaluated on the `if` must be inside parentheses, and there should not be semicolon after it:

```
if (document.getElementById("demo").hasFocus)
{ // do something }
```

This is the first thing you need to change, since this is not even valid javascript. The semicolon indicates the end of a statement.

After you fix that, you are saying that there must be a handler for a click event on a div. Divs are not "focusable" by default, you need to set it's `tabindex` property to 1.

Also, if you want to react on a click, you must add an event listener!

```
someHTMLElement.addEventListener('click', function_to_execute_onclick)
```

Or do you need to react to the click event only when the div is focused?

EDIT:
Well, you only need a button first!

```
<img id = "pic">
<button id = 'play'>Play</button>
```

And the JS:

```
const img = document.getElementById('pic');

function changePicture ()
{ img.src = 'some/pic.jpg'
  // do more stuff on click.
}

document.getElementById('play')
        .addEventListener('click', changePicture);
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that divs don't have a focus state. Basically what i'm trying to accomplish is this:

I have an mp3 audio player and if the user clicks play, the album art will display somewhere else on the page.

Comment: They can be focusable if you set it's `tabindex` property to 1 :)
You then need to add a click event on a button! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Here is the weird thing, I'm using adobe muse to create this. I added the mp3 widget. Now when i open the html file i see the id for that audio widget but thats about it. nothing else. Now when i right click on the page i have it published at and select inspect element, i go to that id and i see way more elements things like an actual button tag, weird right?

Comment: I didn't use Adobe Muse, but if you don't have enough experience to write your own html, you shouldn't use it. Also, I don't know what "extra" code may add it to the web's markup.

Keep it simple, make your own simple page.

Comment: you can see it here: 

http://lesantest.comuf.com/sunshine%20Productions/player.html

now if you look through the code you will notice <button> when i edit the code from the .html file i do not see those tags.

Comment: Which tags are the ones you are not seeing?

Comment: all of these: http://i.imgur.com/KEPORic.png that portion of the code does not appear at all in notepad++